# Can anybody guide me how to protect an IC from air arcing at high voltage test?

Tags: pcb-design, integrated-circuit, isolation, surge-protection, application-note

I want to check the isolation voltage of an IC by applying high AC voltage up to 10kV across the primary and secondary sides of the IC. During this process, I am facing a problem of air arcing above 5kV maybe through creepage or clearance.

Can anybody guide me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you can perform the test in a vacuum chamber?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess it's not the right way. Could you tell me how I can connect it to the high voltage test equipment and IC which I want the test in a vacuum chamber?

Comment: You would need a vacuum chamber equipped with cable glands. Ideally only the 10kV test voltage wires would pass through the vacuum chamber walls. The DUT would be in the chamber, and the test equipment would be outside.

Comment: Why are you testing it anyway? If the IC leads are close enough that you get arcs through air at 5kV, what is the purpose of testing at 10kV? The circuit will never be safe for 10kV anyway since the leads are too close. Unless you encapsulate the circuit with a dielectric material (potting compound).